# Tikz shading doesn't produce proper RGB colors. RGB = 1,1,1 gives a dark gray, not white

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I am trying to shade a dirac cone in tikz, but the color definitions give me a headache as RGB colors are way too dark. Setting all colors to`{rgb:red,1;green,1;blue,1}` would five a dark grey instead of white, so I think something is wrong with the color mixing:

[image]

Here is my sample code with the actual RGB colors that I want to use for the body:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\h{6}
\def\a{2}
\def\b{0.5}
\def\shadebody{\fill[
    left color={rgb:red,65;green,134;blue,198},
    right color={rgb:red,65;green,134;blue,198},
    middle color={rgb:red,126;green,169;blue,208},
    shading=axis,
    opacity=1
    ] }
\def\shadetop{\fill[
    top color={rgb:red,65;green,134;blue,198},
    bottom color={rgb:red,65;green,134;blue,198},
    %middle color={rgb:red,126;green,169;blue,208},
    shading=axis,
    opacity=1
    ] }


\shadebody
  (\a,0) -- (0,\h) -- (-\a,0) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm);
\draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (-\a,0) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm) -- (0,\h) -- cycle;

  %upper part
\shadetop
(0,2*\h) circle (\a cm and \b cm);

\shadebody
  (\a,2*\h) -- (0,\h) -- (-\a,2*\h) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm);
  \draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (-\a,2*\h) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm) -- (0,\h) -- cycle;

  \draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (\a,2*\h) arc (0:180:\a cm and \b cm);






\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I get next to what the gradient looks like in illustrator:
[image]

Maybe you know what I am doing wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: the scale is 0,0,0=black, 255,255,255=white, so 1,1,1=dark gray sounds about right

Comment: The scale is percental, so 255,255,255 gives the same as 1,1,1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using `\definecolor`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\h{6}
\def\a{2}
\def\b{0.5}
\definecolor{top}{RGB}{65,134,198}
\definecolor{middle}{RGB}{126,169,208}
\def\shadebody{\fill[
    left color=top,
    right color=top,
    middle color=middle,
    shading=axis,
    opacity=1
    ] }
\def\shadetop{\fill[
    top color=top,
    bottom color=top,
    middle color=middle,
    shading=axis,
    opacity=1
    ] }


\shadebody
  (\a,0) -- (0,\h) -- (-\a,0) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm);
\draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (-\a,0) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm) -- (0,\h) -- cycle;

  %upper part
\shadetop
(0,2*\h) circle (\a cm and \b cm);

\shadebody
  (\a,2*\h) -- (0,\h) -- (-\a,2*\h) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm);
  \draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (-\a,2*\h) arc (180:360:\a cm and \b cm) -- (0,\h) -- cycle;

  \draw[line width = 0.5pt] 
  (\a,2*\h) arc (0:180:\a cm and \b cm);






\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```